# Longest database entry in Postgresql/ How to save users' heart rate data effectively

Tags: postgresql, django-models

I am making a web app where I will have to get **users' heart rates**, say in **1min intervals** for at least an **hour a day**.

The problem I am facing is this - **how do I design my database so that it can handle this**? 
1 user, 1 hour is 60 values. 10 users, same time, 600 values. Just in one hour.

**I need to plan this for the next 2 years of handling data**. I need to add, that I need to have this data on the server, because I plan on analysing it, and I plan on crunching numbers.

Do I create a heart rate (HR) table, and store values coming from one unique user in one long array?
Also -

If it matters, I am working with Django.

Comment: 600 values an hour is not that much. Database are designed to work with millions of records.

Comment: At 600 an hour a db-cardiologist would be trying to resuscitate the patient. It's dying from lack of activity. 600 a second would be no problem. However "one long array" is a very bad plan.

Comment: @Belayer ok, I got your point. So what would you recommend doing?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ok true, however we are only talking about 10 users here. 
Also, if Belayer is right (which might be the case), what approach would you take to store all these values for each individual user?